# Copying a struct into an array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

I've a struct of the following type

```
typedef struct Edge
{
    int first;
    int second;

}Edge;
```

Which I'm instantiating in my main function and copying into an array

```
Edge h_edges[NUM_EDGES];
for (int i = 0; i < NUM_VERTICES; ++i)
    {
        Edge* e = (Edge*)malloc(sizeof(Edge));
        e->first = (rand() % (NUM_VERTICES+1));
        e->second = (rand() % (NUM_VERTICES+1));
        memcpy(h_edges[i], e, sizeof(e));
    }
```

I keep running into the following error.

```
src/main.cu(28): error: no suitable conversion function from "Edge" to "void *" exists
```

Line 28 is the line where the memcpy happens. Any help appreciated.

Comment: The error is because you have an item `h_edges[i]` of type `Edge` in `memcpy` which is expecting a `void *`. You can't use a struct type in place of a pointer type. You need `memcpy(&h_edges[i], e, sizeof(*e))`. In other words, the *address* of `h_edges[i]` is what you're copying to, and you want the size of *what `e` points to* not the size of `e` itself, which is a pointer (you'd get the size of a pointer). You could also use `sizeof(Edge)` there.

Comment: And... do not cast the return of `malloc`. Just use, `Edge* e = malloc(sizeof(Edge));`.

Comment: If I dont cast the value, this is what I get src/main.cu(25): error: a value of type "void *" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "Edge *"

Comment: Not casting the `malloc` should not generate an error. If it does, there's something else wrong. `Edge *e = malloc(sizeof(Edge));` should work just fine. See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) for details on why you shouldn't cast it.

Comment: Note that because you are using the CUDA compiler driver to compile this code in a .cu file, your code is, in fact, being compiled by a C++ compiler, and C++ rather than C semantics apply to the use of `malloc`. Of course it isn't at all obvious why you are using `malloc`in that code snippet at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to use `malloc` or `memcpy` at all. You can just:

```
Edge h_edges[NUM_EDGES];
for (int i = 0; i < NUM_VERTICES; ++i)   // or should this be NUM_EDGES??
{
    h_edges[i].first = (rand() % (NUM_VERTICES+1));
    h_edges[i].second = (rand() % (NUM_VERTICES+1));
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is indeed much better. But do fix the random number selection if you need good uniformity.

Comment: Yes, this is the better approach.

Answer (score 2):

The first parameter of `memcpy` takes a pointer and the third argument needs to the size of the `struct`, **not** the pointer.

`memcpy(&h_edges[i], e, sizeof(*e));`

is the fix.

But this is ill-advised. Strictly the behaviour of your program is *undefined*. You can't copy a structure using `memcpy` in a defined way. Essentially the reason for this lies in structure packing.

Your best bet is to copy the structure members explicitly. You could build a function to do that.

An other point is that using `%` will introduce statistical bias in your random numbers, unless the modulus is a multiple of the generator's periodicity; which is unlikely.

(A small point, write `Edge* e = malloc(sizeof(Edge));` instead. i.e. drop the cast on the right hand side. It's unnecessary in C.)

Comment: Needs to be `sizeof(*e)` since `e` is a pointer to what's being copied (an `Edge` structure). Or, `sizeof(Edge)`.

Comment: I don't think the `memcpy` of the full structure is undefined behavior. C should consistently define the internal structure of the `struct` just fine. And the type cast on `malloc` is not only unnecessary, [it can cause issues](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Comment: I'm not sure you're correct on that point, I'll check though.

Comment: If you write a function in C that returns a struct, the `gcc` compiler will internally generate a call to `memcpy` to copy the struct for the return value. So I think it's good. :)